# Anychart download broken on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, charts, anychart

I am trying to create a simple word cloud with Any Chart then download it. [this works in Firefox but seems to break in Chrome, since the file never prompts to download](https://playground.anychart.com/JxyjReR0)

My Code:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    // create data   
    var data = [
{x: "learning", value: 80},
{x: "includes", value: 56},
{x: "lists", value: 44},
{x: "meaning", value: 40},
{x: "useful", value: 36},
{x: "different", value: 32}
    ];

    // create a chart and set the data
    var chart = anychart.tagCloud(data);

    // set the chart title
    chart.title("Tag Cloud Chart: Basic Sample");

    // set the container id
    chart.container("container");

    // initiate drawing the chart
    chart.draw();

    chart.saveAsPng({"width": 150, "height": 150, "quality": 0.3, "filename": "my_file"});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your report! We will look into it and update you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome prohibits downloading in iframes, for details check the official [Google Chrome feature description](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280).
So, your code will work correctly in Google Chrome [without using iframe](https://playground.anychart.com/m1QwW2Mb/iframe).
We will research the possibility to avoid this restriction.